# Nighttime Windows 10 ebook reading

Tags: windows-10, ebooks, reading, dark-theme

I use a Windows 10 tablet. I purchased an ebook on the Amazon website. The ebook is technically on their Kindle platform (? wrong word) but you can view the ebook on the Windows 10 tablet using Amazon's Kindle reader website https://read.amazon.com/

Currently, my Windows 10 tablet is using high contrast mode which inverts colors of many things. But it doesn't invert colors for https://read.amazon.com/

What would be my best bet? Is there some program that lets you place a

I could use the magnifying lense to invert, but it inverts the entire screen, which does not mesh well with my current dark, high contrast mode. So basically, most things are already black. So then when I invert colors, everything becomes white which is fine for the ebook but everything else on my screen becomes bright.

What's the most intelligent software recommendation solution to this?

I'd really prefer to be able to read it on the Windows tablet because I have it docked on a tablet holding arm by my bed and it has a 12 inch screen. If I bought a Kindle, it would be a much smaller screen and it would not fit with my Levo tablet stand.

Comment: Your third paragraph is cut off (place a ...)

Comment: the Kindle app?